# Are there political movements that advocate using "Hinduism" as a basis for a society or state?

Tags: religion

I know that, according to the West, Islam has a political aspect or agenda and that is called *Political Islam*.

Political Islam can be understood as a political ideology that promotes the --

> "formation of state and society according to their understanding of Islamic principles" (Wikipedia).

Are there similar political movements that advocate using "Hinduism" as a basis for a society or state?

If so, what is that called?

Comment: You might want also to draw parallels with various Christian-something parties in some European countries (like the German [Christian Democrats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Democratic_Union_of_Germany))

Comment: This seems a very vague question. Most religions have something to say about how society should be organised. But Hinduism isn't a single, homogenous, centralised faith in the way that Roman Catholicism is. Nor is it based on the belief in the infallibility of a single text, as Islam is. So you could ask what Hindu texts and thinkers say about government; or you can ask about Hindu nationalism and parties that claim to defend Hinduism and Hindus; or you can ask how Western thinkers perceive either or both.

Comment: *Political Islam* is not a property of Islam, it's an activity or ideology of some Muslims.  So, to look for a parallel you wouldn't want to look at Hinduism, but at Hindus.  I'd rephrase the question like this: Political Islam can be understood as a political ideology that promotes the "formation of state and society according to their understanding of Islamic principles" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_Islam)).  Are there similar political movements that advocate for using "Hinduism" as a basis for a society or state?

Comment: I haven't DV this, but it's a Q with a super-obvious A in the current form. OTOH, I'm not sure how much the BJP bases its ideology (as opposed to its *symbolism*) on Hinduism precepts, so that might make a better Q.

Comment: @Fizz, I haven't understood your statement.

Comment: E.g. no small part of political Islam argues for sharia as basis of law in their countries. I have no idea if Hinduism has a similar received legal system and if that is pushed by Hindutva.

Comment: Your comment is worth an answer @StuartF. The only difference I have with you is that the *question* is not vague, its *framing* taken from the Judeo-Christian world is misapplied to Hinduism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindutva):

> Hindutva (transl. Hinduness) is the predominant form of Hindu nationalism in India. The term was coined by Chandranath Basu and was propounded as a political ideology by Vinayak Damodar Savarkar in 1923. It is used by the organisation Rashtriya Swayamsevak Sangh (RSS), the Vishva Hindu Parishad (VHP), the Bharatiya Janata Party (BJP) and other organisations, collectively called the Sangh Parivar.
>
> The Hindutva movement has been described as a variant of "right-wing extremism" and as "almost fascist in the classical sense", adhering to a concept of homogenised majority and cultural hegemony. Some analysts dispute the identification of Hindutva with fascism, and suggest Hindutva is an extreme form of conservatism or "ethnic absolutism".

Answer (score -1):

The question asks for the **name** of the political movement that advocate Hinduism as a basis for society or state.

Society or state?

---

**I go with state first.**

No such words exist actually in the present. However, let's call a group of people called ASDFGHJKL. They want Hindu Rastra. Hindu Rastra means "Hindu country". We don't actually have a word to call these movement. Maybe we can call them "Advocates of Hindu Rastra". They advocate a radical form of society.

Hindutva as pointed out in the other answer is a misnomer. It means Hinduness. There is no Litmus test for Hindutva. Maybe there exists a pH scale for Hindutva. A devout Hindu is a worshipper of his land i.e his country because Lord Ram (a God of the Hindus) worshipped his land. He might not fall into the category of the "advocates of Hindu Rastra".

To simplify, "Advocates of Hindu Rastra" is a subset of "Hindutva believers". I safely say if I were to draw the Venn's diagram, the ratio of the subset and the superset would be very big. I leave you with the liberty of the calculation.

---

**Society**

Most Hindus live in India. There are countries where Hindus are in vast numbers. I will explain about India.

Society is diverse in India. That is one thing, it's important for OP as well anyone not from India needs to understand.

Now every village has their own customs. These are sometimes reflected in their lives religiously. People of a place I stayed some time while ate vegetarian food on Monday. People of another place just 10-15 kilometres aways do it on Thursday. I mean most of them do. It is based on some religious belief they hold dear to. It is not just about food. I am from a cosmopolitan place. Some families in one particular place pray every evening. They sing it aloud. Others don't. To be honest, there are villages resided by these people. It is not for Hindus only. When I studied in college, wine shops were shut on Sundays in the city where I stayed. I am a Christian and studied in a Christian College. Most people are Christians there. Now what can someone call these diverse groups of people? We just have words to describe them.